# Sphinxclient search PHP

Tags: php, sphinx

So here I have Sphinx made search.
Sphinx has indexed 2 fields: title and data.
When user inputs a value I want to display all results sorted by relevance ( i think )

For example: 
row 1, has `title`:`foo` and `data`='foo bar'
row 2, has `title`='foo bar' and `data`='foo bar'
if user inputs foo i want row 1 to display first because the title field is 100% match

```
$sphinx = new SphinxClient;
$sphinx->SetServer(SPHINX_HOST,SPHINX_PORT);
$sphinx->SetLimits(0,2,1000);
$sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$sphinx->SetFieldWeights([
    'title' => 100,
    'data' => 1,
]);
$sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
$data = $sphinx->Query('(@title_original '.$full_phrase.' | @data '.$full_phrase.') & @data cover1','index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory this is what `SPH_RANK_SPH04` is for. Use with `setRankingMode`

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#weighting